# How can i add contract attributes programaticly?

Tags: c#, wcf

i have pure an interface like below

```
public interface IPure
{
  Array GetEmployee(int employeeId);
  DataSet GetAllProducts();
  List<string> GetAllSubCategoryNames();
  double AverageSubTotalFromHeaders();
}
```

How can i add contract attributes programaticly my interface at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Attributes are declarative, not imperative.

You can affect the service host at run time, when you configure it, but that's just moving the information from the configuration file to your code.

Comment: it made me bad man :( i can only do this. 

[ServiceContract] 
public interface IWCFinterface : IPure

Comment: you said configure it,how i can configure?

Comment: Configure what exactly? You can't configure the service interface or data contracts at runtime

Comment: Then don't use your existing interfaces. Do it via a façade to decouple.

Comment: i actualy said this.my interfaces make dependency to the wcf's contract attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.addattributes.aspx) could help you.